# Sql equivalent in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have a code such as below in sql(lot more and and not ins but just wanted to list few) i am new to sas and know proc sql a bit etc, learning and exploring everyday,

```
 Select * from table
 Where date=‘20180112’ 
 and type=‘apple’ and location=‘dc’ and not                    
 (columnName)in(‘a’,’b’) And lat=‘ten’
```

I am not able to understand sas equivalent of above sql as below. Can someone please explain sas code of if part and then do

```
  Data sample;
  Set sourcetble; 
 If date=‘20180112’ and type=‘apple’
  And location=‘dc’ then do;
  Blah1=‘rain’
  Blah2=‘something else’
 If columnName in(‘a’, ‘b’) and lat=‘ten’ Then do;
```

Comment: SAS has SQL built in.  See PROC SQL.  You just need a semicolon.

Comment: I do not understand what your question is.  Do you want to see a data step equivalent for the select statement you posted? Or do you want a description of what the data step code is doing? Note that in their current form they are not really close to being equivalent.

Comment: Neither of those are the full code and they're not necessarily equivalent depending on where the END is for the data step.

Answer (score 1):

This just subsets based the values and variables in the WHERE statement.

```
Data sample; 
   set table;
   WHERE date='20180112' and type='apple' And location='dc' 
         and columnName in (‘a’, ‘b’) and lat=‘ten’;
   <other optional code>;
   run;
```

Comment: Sorry i for incomplete code but i basically want sql code’s equivalent in sas and description of what the data step is doing

Comment: @Brita  This data step IS the equivalent of your SQL statement. The data step code in your question is doing something totally different than the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not like SQL query, a SAS data step will result in creating a new dataset. If you don't need to have a new dataset, you can use "data _null_;". Alternatively there are SAS procedures that will simply display dataset such as SQL "select" would do.

The "set" in SAS is equivalent to the "from" in SQL: it specifies the base dataset(s) from which you build the new dataset.

By default, SAS data step keeps all variables of the "set" datasets. It is equivalent to "select *" in SQL. If you need only some variables, you can use "keep" and "drop" statements in SAS.

The "where" clause and "and"/"or" operators work similarly in SAS and SQL, but with slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The `if … then` in the data step has no correspondce to the SQL shown in the question.  A conditional assignment in SQL is done using a `case` statement.

So a DATA step statement such as

```
data want;
  set have;
  … 
  if date="20180112" and type="apple" and location="dc" then do;
    Blah1="rain";
    Blah2="something else";
  end;
```

would be concordant with SQL

```
Proc SQL;
  create table want as
  select …
    , case when date="20180112" and type="apple" and location="dc"
        then "rain"
        else ""
      end as Blah1
    , case when date="20180112" and type="apple" and location="dc"
        then "something else"
        else ""
      end as Blah2
  from
    have
  … 
  ;
```

For the case of some algorithm needing to assign several variables at once when some criteria (`if` logic) is met:

- DATA Step has `do; … end;` syntax which can have several assignments statements within.
- SQL select statement can only assign one variable per logic evaluation (`case statement`), thus the logic code has to be repeated for each variable being assigned based on criteria.